# Syntax in R for breaking up LHS of assignment over multiple lines

Tags: r, syntax

What is the syntax in R to break up the LHS of an assignment over multiple lines? In other programming languages you can do it.

One use case of this (and please don't let this example distract from the general syntactical question), is that because (I believe) R doesn't support loop placeholder variables by reference, so when working with very deep nested data structures (like recursive lists of data frames of lists) in a for loop you can sometimes have a very a long LHS of an assignment, e.g.

```
results$cases[[i]]$samples[[j]]$portions[[k]]$analytes[[l]]$column <- x
```

I know, you might say why not use nested lapplys or something, but that's a separate discussion.

I tried wrapping the LHS in parentheses and you get

```
Error: could not find function "(<-"
```

Comment: It isn’t so much a separate discussion as a discussion of the underlying issue: that line you’ve posted definitely throws up red flags! You have a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968) on your hands. — That said, what exact issue do you have when breaking it up? You *can* break up the assignment, and it will just work. Just remember that virtually every object in R is a *value* so you don’t have reference semantics; you’ll need to assign the objects back to their original names.

Comment: Please provide an answer with code showing how to break up the LHS of an assignment in R over multiple lines

Comment: Maybe what I should've done is not even put an example or use case, because then that distracts people into bring up issues with that and not advising on the title question. But the title question is still valid, what is the syntax in R to break up the LHS of an assignment over multiple lines? Every other major programming language has syntax for this, but for the life of me I cannot find it for R.

Comment: The related question too, if you have for example a deep nested list of recursive lists of data frames (with columns that are nested lists ... and so on). How do you then make an assignment really deep into this large structure without have a VERY long variable on the LHS. Since R has no reference semantics.

Comment: Well my point is, R *has* a syntax for this, so it simply isn’t clear to me why you think otherwise. It would be helpful if you showed us what you tried.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in parentheses put I kept getting: could not find function "(<-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a line break between any 2 characters that aren't part of a name, and that doesn't leave a syntactically complete expression before the line break (so that the parser knows to look for more). None of these look great, but basically after any `[[` or `$` or before `]]` you can put a line break. For example:

```
results$
  cases[[i]]$
    samples[[j]]$
      portions[[k]]$
        analytes[[l]]$
          column <- x
```

Or going to the extreme, putting in every syntactically valid line break (without introducing parentheses which would let you do even more):

```
results$
  cases[[
    i
  ]]$
    samples[[
      j
    ]]$
      portions[[
        k
      ]]$
        analytes[[
          l
        ]]$
          column <-
            x
```

With parentheses, we lose the *"doesn't leave a syntactically complete expression"* rule, because the expression won't be complete until the parenthses close. You can add breaks anywhere except in the middle of a name (object or function name).  I won't bother with nested indentation for this example.

```
(
  results
  $
  cases
  [[
    i
  ]]
  $
  samples
  [[
    j
  ]]
  $
  portions
  [[
    k
  ]]
  $
  analytes
  [[
    l
  ]]
  $
  column
  <-
  x
)
```

If you want to bring attention to the `x` being assigned, you could also use right assignment.

```
x -> results$cases[[i]]$samples[[j]]$
       portions[[k]]$analytes[[l]]$column
```

Comment: I tried the parentheses wrapping and I kept getting a 'could not find function "(<-"' error, that's when I posed the question because that pretty standard way didn't even work user:903061

Comment: So unless I'm missing something and I checked it just now, but your 3rd option, with the parentheses, doesn't work. I got the 'could not find function "(<-"' error

Comment: Simple way to show that parentheses do not work (multi-line or otherwise): x <- 5, (x) <- 1, Error in (x) <- 1 : could not find function "(<-"

Comment: Thanks all for the parentheses correction. Fixed now.

Comment: if you wanted to you could use `invisible(...)` to suppress printing. If being *very* squirrely you could use `i <- base::invisible`; `i(...)` for sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention: the element operator `[[` supports recursive indexing of lists, as documented in `?Extract` under "Recursive (list-like) objects".

One caveat is that you must provide an integer or character index for each level of recursion. Mixtures aren't supported, so you must index by integer if any sublist does not have a `names` attribute.

```r
x <- list(a = list(a1 = 1, a2 = 2), b = list(b1 = 3, b2 = 4))

x[[c(1L, 1L)]]
## [1] 1

x[[c("a", "a2")]]
## [1] 2

x[[c(2L, 1L)]] <- 30
x[[c(2L, 1L)]]
## [1] 30

x[[c("b", "b2")]] <- 40
x[[c("b", "b2")]]
## [1] 40

x[[list(1L, "a1")]]
## Error in x[[list(1L, "a1")]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

You can always implement accessors that do support indices of mixed type:

```r
rget <- function(x, i) {
    if (is.list(i)) {
        for (j in i) {
            x <- x[[j]]
        }
        x
    } else {
        x[[i]]
    }
}

`rset<-` <- function(x, i, value) {
    if (is.list(i)) {
        y <- x
        n <- length(i)
        ii <- integer(n)
        for (k in seq_len(n)) {
            j <- i[[k]]
            ii[k] <- if (is.character(j)) match(j, names(y)) else j
            y <- y[[j]]
        }
        x[[ii]] <- value
    } else {
        x[[i]] <- value
    }
    x
}
```

Then:

```r
rget(x, list(1L, "a1"))
## [1] 1

rset(x, list(1L, "a1")) <- 10
rget(x, list(1L, "a1"))
## [1] 10
```

You would just have to accept the overhead of the `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, useful with recursive list data structures. In my particular example it's recursive list of data frames which have some columns where their entries are each a list of data frame, and so on. But yes you comment very useful for the recursive list scenario

Comment: Well, data frames _are_ lists, so recursive indexing would still work. Try `typeof(as.data.frame(1:10))`.

Comment: Yes I forgot of course data frames are lists. Though I'm trying to figure out the recursive list indexing you showed with the data structure I described, doesn't seem to work? E.g.results$cases is a list, results$cases[[1]] is a data.frame (and also 2, 3, 4, ...), results$cases[[1]]$samples is a list, results$cases[[1]]$samples[[1]] is a data.frame, and so on in nested fashion.

Comment: That wouldn't work for the reason I mention in my answer: `[[` doesn't allow you to mix integer and character indices, i.e., you can't do `results[[list("cases", 1, "samples", 1)]]`, etc. However, see my latest update with `rget` and `rset`.

Comment: Deleted my last comment... I'd stated that the method `[[.data.frame` doesn't support recursive indexing (as another reason why a recursive `results[[i]]` might not work), but it actually does. My comment above still holds.